# Compilation error when I call the match method from BruteForceMatcher_GPU

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, OpenCV 2.4.6.0.1 and Cuda 5.5
I got the following code:

```
BruteForceMatcher_GPU< Hamming >    matcher;
ORB_GPU orb(1000);
GpuMat patternImage_descriptors;
orb(patternImage_g, GpuMat(), patternImage_keypoints, patternImage_descriptors);

// where patternImage_g is an image I'm loading with GpuMat patternImage_g(originalImage)
// after I make it Gray and resizeing it to 640x480

// then I call
vector<GpuMat> descriptors(1);
descriptors[0] = patternImage_descriptors;
matcher.add(descriptors);
// to train the matcher and then

vector< vector<DMatch> > matches;
matcher.match(frame_descriptors, matches);

// Where frame_descriptors were extracted via ORB_GPU
```

and then I get this compilation error:

```
MatchingEngineGPU.cpp: In member function 'void 
MatchingEngineGPU::processFrameFromFile(const Frame&, Frame&)':
MatchingEngineGPU.cpp:28:43: error: no matching function for call to
 'cv::gpu::BruteForceMatcher_GPU<cv::Hamming>::match(cv::gpu::GpuMat&,
 std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> >&)'
MatchingEngineGPU.cpp:28:43: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1388:10: note: void
 cv::gpu::BruteForceMatcher_GPU_base::match(const cv::gpu::GpuMat&, const
 cv::gpu::GpuMat&, std::vector<cv::DMatch>&, const cv::gpu::GpuMat&)
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1388:10: note:   candidate expects 4
 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1404:10: note: void
 cv::gpu::BruteForceMatcher_GPU_base::match(const cv::gpu::GpuMat&,
 std::vector<cv::DMatch>&, const std::vector<cv::gpu::GpuMat>&)
/usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1404:10: note:   no known conversion
 for argument 2 from 'std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> >' to
 'std::vector<cv::DMatch>&'
```

Compilation command:

```
g++ *.hpp *.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

And I've checked the documentation for BruteForceMatcher_GPU and it has the following function:

```
void match(const GpuMat& query, std::vector<DMatch>& matches,
    const std::vector<GpuMat>& masks = std::vector<GpuMat>());
```

It might be just a C++ logic error but for the life of me I can't figure it out, please help me.

Comment: Please always past a self-contained snippet for compilation errors, including the main function, and the compilation command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message *and* the documentation state, `match` takes a reference to `std::vector<DMatch>`, *not* a `std::vector<std::vector<DMatch>>`, which is what you're passing.